# How to activate gif image in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gif, mousehover

I am trying to make a Vertical menu with a gif image which should activate on mouse hover. 
I have added the image to my page, but the image is not getting active. It is still!!

.... Code used for adding image...

```
   image.setUrl("/Image/menu.gif");
    image.setSize("80px", "80px");
    homepageVpanel.add(image);
```

Comment: As far as I know, animated GIF images should autoplay on most browsers. If yours is static, it probably has nothing to do with GWT. Are you sure the GIF is animated?

Comment: @walen yes, its a gif image and is working normally, but when I am setting it to my client page it is not working.

Comment: Where is "menu.gif" stored?

Comment: menu.gif is stored in Image folder under war folder of the same project